# Include an iframe in a SSRS report

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Is it possible to embed a iframe within a SSRS report so that the viewer of the report sees a standard SSRS report but with some content from a link within the same domain.

Comment: Did you manage to do it ? How did you make the iframe take the size of the reports ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, it is necessary to edit .asp net server page containing the SSRS report,
in my case, pages are at:
..\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.RPT\Reporting Services\ReportManager\Pages

Comment: Does this mean the iframe will display on each report that runs on the report server? Or there is a way to configure it to display on selected report(s)?